# What does isspace (ch & 0xff) mean?

Tags: c

I was reading a source code file. But I got stuck at the following line

```
while (isspace (* bp & 0xff))
    ++ bp;
```

I know the basic idea is to remove the spaces. But I don't know what `0xff` is exactly doing here in the following function.

```
static enum tokens scan (const char * buf)
{
    static const char * bp;

if (buf)
    bp = buf;       /* new input line */

while (isspace (* bp & 0xff))
    ++ bp;

if (isdigit (* bp & 0xff) || * bp == '.')
{
    errno = 0;
    token = NUMBER, number = strtod (bp, (char **) & bp);
    if (errno == ERANGE)
        error ("bad value: %s", strerror (errno));
}
else
token = * bp ? * bp ++ : 0;

    return token;
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `bp`?

Comment: Please show us the surrounding code, in particular the definition and contents of `bp`.

Comment: The Author has years of programming experience. And at first he wrote that like    isspace (* bp) but then he changed it. So, I'm looking here for a meaningful reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation is forcing zeros left of value.
[OR]
The operation ***ch & 0xff** select first 8 bits and **isspace** verify if value is space char.

Comment: Or, taking the 8 least significant bits of `*bp`.

Comment: Thanks , I think i found my answer. Since char is promoted to int in isspace() with the concerned lines author wants to make sure its a ansi-c char always. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The `isspace` function and the other `ctype.h` function expect an `int` as argument. From the C11 standard section 7.4/1:

> The header  declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, **the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char`** or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

This means that if you have code such as:

```
char ch = 'é';   // same as: char ch = -126; for some code pages

isspace(ch);
```

then this call causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).

The rationale for this is so that the function can be implemented as a lookup table:  `#define isspace(x)  space_table[x]`

Causing undefined behaviour is bad of course, so `isspace(ch)` is wrong. The correct way to fix the code is:

```
isspace( (unsigned char)ch );
```

On a machine that uses 2's complement arithmetic, then `ch & 0xFF` is exactly equivalent to `(unsigned char)ch`.

On a machine that doesn't use 2's complement then it will look up the wrong value (but not cause undefined behaviour).

Perhaps your programmer was happy to assume that his code would never run on a non-2's complement machine with negative character codes for whitespace, and he felt that `& 0xFF` was more aesthetic than a cast.

Comment: I do not  want to believe that any compiler vendor would ever write isspace (and any other such function) in a way that it cannot be used for `char c` whatever is in this `c`... Can you show me an example of such compiler?

Comment: @PiotrNycz I can only show the C standard which governs all compilers

Comment: Obviously there was such a compiler in the past, otherwise the ANSI C authors wouldn't have felt obliged to write the standard this way to support such a compiler

Comment: `(ch & 0xFF)` does nothing for signed chars. `-1 & 0xFF` is still -1.

Comment: @M.M You are cheating ;) %d is the wrong parameter. Use %hhd and see it working.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich `ch & 0xFF` has type `int`, so `%d` is the right specifier. You seem to be forgetting about the integer promotions. Try `sizeof(ch & 0xFF)` if unconvinced.

Comment: M.M. If you would use `printf("%hhd", c);` with c being a char, there would be no point in also adding `& 0xFF`. And..if char is actually unsigned on the platform, it really serves no purpose ever. I mean, we agree on the problem. For some reason I get downvotes and you get upvotes. Sometimes I don't get SO.

Comment: @PiotrNycz In MS VC 2005, AFAIR, isspace( 0xFFFF ) will crash with access violation. Seen with other compilers too.

Comment: @c-smile Your example does not show that `isspace` will not work with `char c = 0xffff; isspace(c);`

Comment: @PiotrNycz if `char` is `signed char` in your compiler then even that expression will fail.

Comment: @c-smile An compiler (gcc on x86) where char is signed (CHAR_MIN is negative) - and it works well: ideone.com/qCr8Id

Comment: @LarsFriedrich Maybe something you consider correct actually isn't. Which is great, after all.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich `printf("%hhd", c);` with `c` being a char, has nothing to do with this question. `ch & 0xFF` is an `int`. The reason I'm getting upvotes and you downvotes is that I'm right and you're wrong

Answer (score 2):

Computing an AND operation with `0xFF` extracts the lowest byte, assuming 8 bits per byte. There's no effect for non-negative values, but `char` can also be signed and in that case the resulting `int` can't be represented in an `unsigned char`; taking the lowest byte solves this problem.

Technically, in the expression `ch & 0xFF`, the operands are promoted to `int`, which might have scared the programmer because the parameter of `isspace` is an `int`, but the value shall fit into an `unsigned char` or have the value `EOF`, which can only be represented with `int`s.

Comment: Try this: `char ch =  -2; printf("%d\n", ch & 0xFF);`

Comment: @M.M Thanks, good point, I didn't consider possible negative values.